# Fetch date with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to Python. I'm attempting to scrape a website for information, mostly text, but I have encountered a problem with the date. It looks like this:

```
<time class="jlist_date_image" datetime="2015-04-02 14:30:12">Idag <span class="list_date">14:30</span></time>
```

What I want from this is "2015-04-02 14:30:12". My problem is its not text. Could anyone help me.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the problem? You have a `time` tag with a specific `class`. It contains the `datetime` attribute. A simple google search and checking out the docs would suffice to solve your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = '''<time class="jlist_date_image" datetime="2015-04-02 14:30:12">Idag <span class="list_date">14:30</span></time>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> for i in soup.findAll('time'):
        if i.has_attr('datetime'):
            print(i['datetime'])


2015-04-02 14:30:12
```

Answer (score 6):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BeautifulSoup(strng).time.attrs['datetime']
```