# Fetch date as date, not as number with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've found this other question to fetch a date when **scraping** a website.

However, the solution provided gives me a integer representation, when the desire ouput is a date.

[Fetch date with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413504/fetch-date-with-beautifulsoup)

> Prefered format: 09 de julio del 2019

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ec_editorial = requests.get("https://elcomercio.pe/opinion/editorial")

ec_editorial_scr = ec_editorial.content

data = """your html goes here""" 
soup = BeautifulSoup(ec_editorial_scr)

for i in soup.findAll('time'):
        if i.has_attr('datetime'):
            print(i['datetime'])
```

**prints**

```
1560076500
1559990100
1559990100
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming **1560076500** are unix timestamps,

```
import datetime
time_stamp = 1559990100
converted_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time_stamp / 1e3)
print(converted_date)
print(str(converted_date)
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 19, 6, 49, 50, 100000)
'1970-01-19 06:49:50.100000'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here (You can 'play' with the format string in order to get the exact output)

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ec_editorial = requests.get("https://elcomercio.pe/opinion/editorial")
soup = BeautifulSoup(ec_editorial.content, 'html.parser')
for i in soup.findAll('time'):
    if i.has_attr('datetime'):
        print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(int(i['datetime']))))
```

output

```
2019-06-09 13:35:00
2019-06-08 13:35:00
2019-06-08 13:35:00
2019-06-07 13:35:00
2019-06-06 13:35:00
....
```

Answer (score 1):

1560076500, 1559990100 are epoch time, i.e. the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 (midnight UTC/GMT).

Easiest way to convert those into string format are using Python `time` library.

1. Convert the epoch integer value to `localtime`.

```
>>> date = 1560076500
>>> import time
>>> date = time.localtime(date)
>>> date
time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=9, tm_hour=16, tm_min=5, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=160, tm_isdst=0)
```

2. Use `strftime()` to format into string.

```
>>> time.strftime('%d %b %Y', date)
'09 Jun 2019'
```